# Close and Open new Window PYQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to press a button in a window and close that window,after that open a new window

How can I do it?

I already tried it but it sends this message the console:

QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title = 'pySim Z-eighty'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 1200
        self.height = 3000
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.button = QPushButton("Z80")
        self.button1 = QPushButton()
        self.button2 = QPushButton()
        self.container =    QWidget()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 2)
        self.container.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layoutPrincipal = QBoxLayout(0)
        self.layoutPrincipal.addWidget(self.container)
        self.setLayout(self.layoutPrincipal)
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.IniciarInterfaz)

    def IniciarInterfaz(self):
        self.hide()
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = mainWindow()
        ex.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fff")
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My main problem is when i pressed the button I can't open the new window

Comment: show your code.

Comment: To improve your question you should read the content that shows the following link: [ask], The cause of the problem can be due to several causes and we do not want to waste time in guessing.

Comment: My problem is that when i press the button Z80 and call self.IniciarInterfaz,it can´t open my new window

Comment: what is mainWindow?

Comment: the new window,i wanna open with the button Z80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can only be one `QApplication` within the `PyQt` application, so if you already created it, do not do it again.

Another problem is that the variables exist only within the context, in your case mainWindow, so at the end of the function StartInterface will eliminate this variable and the window, the solution is to make the mainWindow member of the class, so the context will be the class and no longer the function, so it will stay correctly.

```
def IniciarInterfaz(self):
    self.hide()
    self.ex = mainWindow()
    self.ex.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fff")
    self.ex.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

PYQT No open and close method,...

hide() and show() method you can use buttons what ever you want,...

```py
def PlatformType_Clicked(self):
    dialog.hide()
    dialog1.show()
```